# Docker inspect vs docker manifest difference in layer digests

Tags: docker

I have built a child image with base image alpine:3.3. If I inspect the newly built child image using command `docker inspect` then I see first layer digest inside **RootFS** tag of child image as same as base image.

Now same child image is inspected through docker-hub manifest API or `docker manifest` command, then I see different layer digests.

Why layer digests are different when we do `docker inspect` and when we do `docker manifest` on the same child image?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The digests are based on the bytes of the file managed locally or blob pushed to the registry server. Locally this file is a tar of the layer. However when pushing to a registry, this tar gets compressed, and the digest is computed in this compressed tar file. So the difference you are seeing is usually from compression.