# Tracing Docker manifest layers

Tags: docker

I would like to find a way to trace the layers that exist on a remote container registry back to the layers in the image, and eventually back to the actual instructions in the Dockerfile.

From the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692401/docker-inspect-vs-docker-manifest-difference-in-layer-digests) we can see that there is a difference between the SHAs output from the `docker manifest inspect` and the `docker image inspect -f '{{.RootFS.Layers}}'` command. The layers described by `docker manifest inspect` match up to the layer references on the remote registry.

How can I match up the layers from `docker manifest inspect` to the layers in `docker image inspect` to the commands in `docker history`?

`docker history` shows all the IMAGE tags as `<missing>` except for the first one, so I'm not even sure it can be matched to.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to [Docker inspect vs docker manifest difference in layer digests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57692401/docker-inspect-vs-docker-manifest-difference-in-layer-digests/63547952#63547952)

Basically the manifest layers are after compression, and the RootFs layers are before compression.